# How to handle MySQL heavy traffic?

Tags: mysql, database-design, split, server

Having a MySQL site with 90,000 accounts, you need to split traffic into two or three servers, how to do this, the site runs on MySQL. The site has many queries to the database, more Insert than select. How to split this traffic into several servers, and if possible optimize the database (to reduce the number of links)?

I will add that I do not want to change the database for this time to better e.g MemSQL because I do not know about it and the current development. In the future I have such an intention.

Comment: You could consider a three way partition of your MySQL database.  The partitions themselves could even be in strategic locations which make sense for the requests you expect to come in.

Comment: Are you suggesting on each server to make a copy of the database, and when adding an insert to each of them add the same record and when downloading the data, download one of the servers and select?

Comment: No, I'm suggesting a _partition_ of the database.  If you don't have experience with this, SO questions is probably not the best approach.  Start by reading MySQL's documentation of partitions.

Comment: We use one master for "inserts only" and several replicas for "selects only". So far it works very well - we have several dozens of millions of inserts per day and around million of selects per day but some of them are really heavy. Try here - http://serverfault.com/questions/236394/how-can-i-have-2-database-servers-for-my-website

Comment: I need to handle about one million inserts and three million select in an hour.
What configurations can I use according to you?

Comment: I was thinking of cloud computing search for it also read this article http://www.scaledb.com/large-database.php

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is to use database virtualization, you can use PAR elastic software for this.

Many consider it essential to use a NoSQL database for high data ingestion rates. This is simply not true.

While it is true that a single MySQL server in the cloud cannot ingest data at high rates; often no more than a few thousand rows a second when inserting in small batches, or tens of thousands of rows a second using a larger batch size. However, **database virtualization** software from **ParElastic** is able to scale MySQL servers to hundreds of thousands and even more than **1,000,000 (one million) rows per second**.