# how to handle large traffic data

Tags: performance, load-balancing

How to handle large traffic sites? 
Please correct me if I am wrong or is there some more methods that have to be taken care

1. Caching
2. Horizontal scaling
3. CDN for static links like images,css,js
4. Database insert should be queued
5. Load balancer

[How to handle MySQL heavy traffic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43362988/how-to-handle-mysql-heavy-traffic)

Comment: Those are all good starting points. I think this is probably too broad for SO format though. There are many good articles / books on this, inc this one: https://www.amazon.com/Building-Scalable-Web-Sites-Applications/dp/0596102356

Comment: thx @matthew but are the points ok to get it started as i have searched few blogs and videos but not getting concrete answer for it